# Automatically begin and end a table \ run code before first instance and after last instance of repeated macro

Tags: macros

I'm writing a class for a document that formats a lot of simple paragraphs as tables. I know, that all tables follow a fixed number of columns, but have a variable number of rows. What I would like to do is writing a macro, that if issued once creates a single-row table and if issued n-times creates an n-row table. I'm interested in a general solution, that allows to insert any piece of code before the first instance of a macro and after the last but not in-between repeated calls to the same macro. Below is a minimal example of what output I want to achieve:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrarticle}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

One row example: 

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Some & Text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

Two row example:

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Some & Text\\
\hline
Other & Line\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

I want to have a command that allows me to just write the table rows and everything else is added automatically. So with a hypothetic command `autotable` the above example would look like:

```
[...]
\begin{document}
One row example: 

\autotable{Some}{Text}

Two row example:

\autotable{Some}{Text}
\autotable{Other}{Line}

\end{document}
```

A concise answer explaining why that is not possible (if so) would also be quite helpful as I could achieve something like this using python/jinja instead if needed. Not completely unrelated questions: [Look-ahead on token stream?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433234/look-ahead-on-token-stream), [Macro: Expand differently depending on pattern?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294808/macro-expand-differently-depending-on-pattern)

**Edit**

This is the code taken from the accepted solution by David with added `\hlines` so the output created matches the exact output from the initial minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrarticle}

\makeatletter

\def\autotable{\par\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\autotable@row}

\def\autotable@row#1#2{%
#1&#2
\@ifnextchar\autotable\autotable@gobble{\\\hline\end{tabular}\par}}

\def\autotable@gobble#1{\\\hline\autotable@row}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

One row example: 

\autotable{Some}{Text}

Two row example:

\autotable{Some}{Text}
\autotable{Other}{Line}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\@ifnextchar` to lookahead, skipping over the white space from end of line

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrarticle}

\makeatletter

\def\autotable{\par\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\autotable@row}

\def\autotable@row#1#2{%
#1&#2%
\@ifnextchar\autotable\autotable@gobble{\end{tabular}\par}}

\def\autotable@gobble#1{\\\autotable@row}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

One row example: 

\autotable{Some}{Text}

Two row example:

\autotable{Some}{Text}
\autotable{Other}{Line}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thank you David. Any way to get the `\hline` working as well?

Comment: @Dschoni you mean to place it where you explicitly `not in-between repeated calls to the same macro.` said nothing would be placed? :-) If you always want `\hline` just add it after the `\\ ` in autotable@gobbe, if only sometimes then it depends on the syntax perhaps easiest to make it an optional argument so `\autotable[\hline]{this}{that}` although an option which only allows \hline is a bit odd

Comment: @Dschoni or you could decide the fact that `\autotable{\hline this}{that}` works and call it a feature.

Comment: Thanks David, I've figured out where to place my hlines and will update my question with it! A lot learned by this...

Comment: David, could you please give me a hint where to find more info on this "aliased" function names using the `@` syntax? I seem to be to dumb to google that...

Comment: @Dschoni there is no "@ syntax", `@` is simply being used as a letter here. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do